# Context Menu on QGraphicsWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, contextmenu, qt-contextmenu

In my application I have two object type. One is field item, other is composite item.
Composite items may contain two or more  field items.
Here is my composite item implementation.

```
#include "compositeitem.h"

CompositeItem::CompositeItem(QString id,QList<FieldItem *> _children)
{
   children = _children;
}

CompositeItem::~CompositeItem()
{
}

QRectF CompositeItem::boundingRect() const
{
 FieldItem *child;
     QRectF rect(0,0,0,0);
     foreach(child,children)
     {
        rect = rect.united(child->boundingRect());
     }
    return rect;
}

void CompositeItem::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,   QWidget *widget )
  {
   FieldItem *child;
   foreach(child,children)
   {
      child->paint(painter,option,widget);
   }
  }

  QSizeF CompositeItem::sizeHint(Qt::SizeHint which, const QSizeF &constraint) const
  {
   QSizeF itsSize(0,0);
   FieldItem *child;
   foreach(child,children)
   {
      // if its size empty set first child size to itsSize
      if(itsSize.isEmpty())
          itsSize = child->sizeHint(Qt::PreferredSize);
      else
      {
          QSizeF childSize = child->sizeHint(Qt::PreferredSize);
              if(itsSize.width() < childSize.width())
                  itsSize.setWidth(childSize.width());
              itsSize.setHeight(itsSize.height() + childSize.height());
      }
  }
  return itsSize;
     }

     void CompositeItem::contextMenuEvent(QGraphicsSceneContextMenuEvent *event)
     {
          qDebug()<<"Test";
     }
```

My first question is how I can propagate context menu event to specific child.

[image: composite1]

Picture on the above demonstrates one of my possible composite item.

If you look on the code above you will see that I print "Test" when context menu event occurs.

When I right click on the line symbol I  see that "Test" message is printed.
But when I right click on the signal symbol "Test" is not printed and I want it to be printed.

My second question what cause this behaviour.
How do I overcome this.

Comment: I cant find your first question, what it was about?

Comment: @mosg Sorry I forgot to write my first question. I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try reimplementing your contextMenu with the mouseRelease event instead?

```
void CompositeItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
        if(event->button() == Qt::RightButton)
        {
            contextMenu->popup(QCursor::pos());
        }
}
```

Comment: Due to an advice I edited boundingRect code. I guess it is a neat idea to unite childs boundingRects. But this time item can' t catch events like contextmenuevent and mousepressevent. So my prior problem is to catch events. Do you have an idea what may cause this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that there may be two solutions for catching events.
First one is reimplementing [shape](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qgraphicsitem.html#shape) function.
In my case it will be implemented like this.

```
QPainterPath shape() const
{
  QPainterPath path;
  path.addRect(boundingRect());
  return path;
}
```

Second one is to use [QGraphicsItemGroup](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsitemgroup.html)

It will be good idea to use [QGraphicsItemGroup](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsitemgroup.html) if you diretly adding your items to scene. But in my case I have to subclass [QGraphicsItemGroup](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qgraphicsitemgroup.html) because of I am using a layout.
So temporarily I choose writing my own item.